# How to select checkbox one by one when it reaches the last checkbox button change from select to unselect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a button written select I want to change it to unselect when I select checkbox manual one by one when it reaches to the last checkbox text must change to unselect and when I uncheck it must goes back to select. I am using prototype scripting.

```
    y += '<button id="button1" class="button4" onclick="SwitchButtons(\'button1\'); 
         selects()" class="sideviewtoggle myButton">';
      y += '<i class="mdi-checkbox-multiple-marked-outline mdi"  data-type="unchecked" > 
      </i>Select All</button>';
      y += '<button id="button2" class="button4"onclick="SwitchButtons(\'button2\'); 
     deSelect()" class="sideviewtoggle myButton" style="display:none;">';
    y += '<i class="mdi-checkbox-multiple-blank-outline mdi" ></i>Unselect 
    All</button>';

    for (var z = 0; z < data.length; z++) {
     y += '<tr id="record-';
     y += data[z].id;
     y += '" class="tb">';

     y += '<td><input  class="select" id="select_'+z+'"  type=checkbox  record="record- 
  ';
   y += data[z].id;
   y += '" name="chk" onclick="selectDone('+z+')"></td>';
     if (a.addrowcount == true) {
    y += '<td>';
    y += z + 1;
    y += '</td>';
  }

  function selectDone(x) {
   var g = "select_"+x;
   var b = document.getElementById(g);

   var unselect = document.getElementById("button2");
   var select = document.getElementById("button1");
   if((b.checked = true)>=1) 
   {
  
      unselect.style.display = "block";
      select.style.display = "none";
   } 
 }
```

Comment: Please add html as well

Comment: It appears that you will be generating duplicate IDs - any code that relies upon ID attributes for selection/processing will fail as a result

Comment: @SrushtiShah my code is too long that why i din't incude everything if so i can include everything

Comment: It also appears that you are generating invalid markup by adding buttons outwith the table structure. Elements may have only 1 `class` attribute - not two

Comment: So i have to put button inside the table? @ProfessorAbronsius

Comment: the buttons **must** be inside a table-cell ( or NOT in the table at all )! Rather than multi-line concatenation (as above ) it is easier to use [template-literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0):

as per what i understood, you need to append button's value according to the checked boxes, so if you have all boxes checked, you need the button to display "Unselect" otherwise it will display "Select"

here's what you need if i understood your question right!

```js
let rootelm = document.querySelector('#root')
let button = document.querySelector('#check')
for( let i =0; i< 6; i++){
  rootelm.innerHTML += `<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="sometext" id="checkbox${i+1}" name="checkbox${i+1}" /><label for="checkbox${i+1}">chk${i+1}</label><br />` 
}
let chkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
chkboxes.forEach((box) => {
    box.addEventListener('change', () => {
      let chked = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
      if(chked.length == chkboxes.length){ 
        button.value ="Unselect"
      } else { 
        button.value = "Select"
      }
  });
})
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<input type="button" id="check" value="Select" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort this what I want.

Comment: @Justice
sounds good, gl with the rest, please set your question as answered by checking the right answer as correct to let other people who have the same question find the right answer